# Vaadin Websecurity connect to h2 database forbidden

Tags: spring-security, vaadin, h2

I downloaded the Vaadin Starter with Spring security. The application is working fine and I just wanted to take a look in the database.
The h2-console is accessable via localhost:8080/h2-console and I see in the logs that

H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:83bc661d-5c93-4354-acbc-1960e90e5406'

When I try to access it and push "connect", I get and 403.

I tried

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{

    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll();

    http.csrf().disable();
    http.headers().frameOptions().disable();

    super.configure(http);
    setLoginView(http, LoginView.class, LOGOUT_URL);

}
```

but there is an

`super.configure(http);`

after it and the configuration is overridden. Without this super call the whole application crashes.

Is there a way to use all the Vaadin stuff and are able to access the h2 database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must take care of the order of the configuration. Like this it works

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{

    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll();

    super.configure(http);
    setLoginView(http, LoginView.class, LOGOUT_URL);

    http.csrf().disable();
    http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked fine and I will use it like it is